# Clang Format chained else ifs on single lines

Tags: c++, clang-format

I'm trying to write a .clang-format file that will allow the following:

```
if (value.Is<bool>()) { index = 1; }
else if (value.Is<int>()) { index = 2; }
else if (value.Is<unsigned int>()) { index = 3; }
else if (value.Is<long long>()) { index = 4; }
else if (value.Is<unsigned long long>()) { index = 5; }
else if (value.Is<float>()) { index = 6; }
else if (value.Is<double>()) { index = 7; }
else if (value.Is<long double>()) { index = 8; }
else if (value.Is<std::string>()) { index = 9; }
else if (value.IsArray()) { index = 10; }
else { index = 0; }
```

I've tried every option I can find related to breaks and allowShort*, and no matter what I do it seems to split them into multi-lines after the first like so:

```
if (value.Is<bool>()) { index = 1; }
else if (value.Is<int>()) {
  index = 2;
}
...
```

Is there some option I'm missing that could support this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is currently not supported for if-else statements, only for simple if's (as of revision 329373, dating 6/4/18). The `AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine` and `AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine` options are not applicable for if-else statements.

Hopefully this will change in the future.

---

The [doc](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) is not explicit about this, saying that `AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine` will allow simple if statements on a single line:

> **AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine (bool)**
>       If true, `if (a) return;` can be put on a single line.

However, clang-format code suggests that if-else blocks are not allowed on single lines:

1) [UnwrappedLineFormatter.cpp](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/lib/Format/UnwrappedLineFormatter.cpp), *tryMergeSimpleControlStatement*:

```
// Only inline simple if's (no nested if or else).
if (I + 2 != E && Line.startsWith(tok::kw_if) &&
    I[2]->First->is(tok::kw_else))
  return 0;
```

2) [FormatTest.cpp](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/unittests/Format/FormatTest.cpp), *FormatShortBracedStatements* test.
   Notice the test parameters, and that in the expected formatting in the unittests, else always resides in its own line, while plain if statements with no else are on a single line with their blocks, for example:

```
verifyFormat("if (true) {\n"
             "  f();\n"
             "} else {\n"
             "  f();\n"
             "}",
  AllowSimpleBracedStatements);
```

Comment: Do you know an answer for this in newer clang-format versions?

Answer (score 1):

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html says:

> SIS_AllIfsAndElse (in configuration: AllIfsAndElse) Always put short ifs, else >ifs and else statements on the same line.

```
if (a) return;

if (b) return;
else return;

if (c) return;
else {
  return;
}
```